# how to implement wrapbootstrap themes in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a rails app, also I have integrated but i don't know integrate a wrapbootstrap in rails?. Any idea to how to do this ?

I'm new and I don't found any example about this.

Comment: From what I understand wrapbootstrap is just a theme, so basically you just need to structure your html files like the theme does, move the css and js into your assets/stylesheets, assets/javascripts respectively and build from there. There's no one click way to integrate an entire theme.

Comment: Then I need to put the content whitin a div for example <div class="modal" id="new_image"></div>. And call the div with <%= link_to "Agregar Imagenes","#new_image", :data => {:toggle=>"modal"},
:class=>"btn"%> ?. But How I can render the _form on div modal ?

Comment: If you want to render a form in the modal, just render the partial inside of the modal code.